# Editing xml file with CDATA

Tags: php, xml, editing

I am editing the xml file using this code

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file($xmlfile) or die ("Unable to load XML file!"); 
$event->title = $newtitle;
$event->description = $newdescription;
file_put_contents($xmlfile, $xml->asXML());
```

I want to add a CDATA in description.I used this code

```
$event->description = '<![CDATA['.$newdescription.']]>';
```

But in xml the `<` and `>` are converted as `&lt;` and `&gt;`.How i can retain `CDATA` as it is .Is any other method for editing.Thanks in advance.

Actually i want to edit this xml file

```
<events date="06-11-2010">
    <event id="8">
      <title>Proin porttitor sollicitudin augue</title>
      <description><![CDATA[Lorem  nunc.]]></description>
    </event>
  </events>
  <events date="16-11-2010">
    <event id="4">
      <title>uis aliquam dapibus</title>
      <description><![CDATA[consequat vel, pulvinar.</createCDATASection></description>
    </event>
  <event id="1"><title>You can use HTML and CSS</title>
  <description><![CDATA[Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet]]></description></event></events>
```

With id

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that you need to use [DOM](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php) when your needs are more complex and no longer *simple*. There is a method [createCDATASection](https://www.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.createcdatasection.php).

Here's a basic example:

```
$dom=new DOMDocument();
$xml='data.xml';
$dom->load($xml);
$cdata=$dom->createCDATASection('<p>Foo</p>');
foreach ($dom->getElementsByTagName('item') as $item) {
    $item->getElementsByTagName('content')->item(0)->appendChild($cdata);
}

$dom->save($xml);
```

The XML that goes with this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<data>
    <item>
        <title>Test</title>
        <content><![CDATA[<p>Foo</p>]]></content>
    </item>
</data>
```

With regards to your example and comment, the following should help you:

```
$dom=new DOMDocument();
$dom->validateOnParse = true;

$xml='data.xml';
$dom->load($xml);

// Unless the ID attribute is recognised
foreach ($dom->getElementsByTagName('event') as $event) { 
    $event->setIdAttribute('id', true);
}

$event = $dom->getElementById("1");
foreach ($event->getElementsByTagName('description') as $description) {
    $cdata=$dom->createCDATASection('<p>'. $description->nodeValue .'</p>');
    $description->replaceChild($cdata, $description->childNodes->item(0));
}

$dom->save($xml);
```

Comment: thanks Cez.I edited my question.I want to edit the content with corresponding id.Can u tell how is it?

Comment: @THOmas: I've added an example based upon your XML. Hopefully, it should point you in the right direction

Comment: is their any way to link with xpath and xquery or dom_import_simplexml

Comment: @THOmas: Yes, take a look at DOMXPath http://php.net/manual/en/domxpath.query.php

Comment: @THOmas: If you are expecting output from the code, then do not use $dom->save($xml) and use $dom->saveXML() instead. DOMDocument::save writes to file, DOMDocument::saveXML writes to a string

Answer (score 2):

Essentially, `SimpleXML` will escape all values for XML use, so a lot of the reasons to use `CDATA` nodes aren't there. If you do need them however, it cannot be done in `SimpleXML`, use another alternative like `DOMDocument` and it's function [`createCDATASection()`](http://nl.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.createcdatasection.php)

Comment: Erm, despite you having 2 links instead of my 1, you were a few seconds earlier I believe...

Comment: @Wrikken: sleep deficit means that I can't tell the time. Do I get an upvote for being tired?

Comment: can u explain how i can edit using `DOMDocument` and `createCDATASection()`

Comment: There's [quite a literal example](http://www.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.createcdatasection.php#76905) in the docs...

Comment: @THOmas: I've added a basic example for you to my answer

Answer (score -2):

Try

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file($xmlfile,'SimpleXMLElement', LIBXML_NOCDATA);
```

?